# Non-English Characters in JSON

Tags: iphone, json, ipad

I'm using a JSON file which contains non-English characters.Hence when I'm fetching values from this file, it is showing some Chinese like characters in the simulator.In the console, I'm getting values like

```
\U2021\U00c6\U00e1\U2021\U00c6\U00a9\U2021\U00d8\U00e7\U2021\U00c6\U00b1\U2021\U00d8
\U00e0\U2021\U00c6\U00d8\U2021\U00c6\U00d6\U2021\U00c6\U2264\U2021\U00c6\U2122\U2021
\U00d8\U00e7\U2021\U00c6\U2122\U2021\U00c6\U00b1\U2021\U00d8\U00e0\U2021\U00c6\U00ef
\U2021\U00d8\U00e7 \U2021\U00c6\U00ef\U2021\U00d8\U00c7\U2021\U00c6\U00fc...
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is the problem, can you be more clear on the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to print in such way:

```
NSString *currentString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:characterBuffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
NSLog(@"Converted string: %@", currentString);
```

where `characterBuffer` is buffer where you've collected received data, replace `NSUTF8StringEncoding` with appropriate encoding, used at your server.